# Redux state properties not initialized correctly in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, react-hooks, react-redux

I am working on a React Redux application where I have two properties in the global state called `time` and `timerId`. The time property is initialized with a default value of 0, and the `timerId` property is initialized with null.

**actions**

```
export const timerSet = (payload: number) => ({ type: TIMER_SET, payload });
export const setTime = (payload: number) => ({ type: SET_TIME, payload });
```

**reducer**

```
export const initialState: State = {
    preferences: {
        time: 0,
    },
    time: {
        timer: 1,
        timerId: null,
    },
};

const timerReducer = (
    state = initialState.time,
    { type, payload }: AnyAction
) => {
    switch (type) {
        case TIMER_SET:
            return { ...state, timer: payload };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

const preferenceReducer = (
    state = initialState.preferences,
    { type, payload }: AnyAction
) => {
    switch (type) {
        case SET_TIME:
            return {
                ...state,
                time: payload,
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

In one of my components, I have two useEffect hooks. The first one fetches data from a JSON file and sets the time property based on the value retrieved from local storage. The second useEffect hook listens to changes in the time property and updates the UI accordingly.

However, I am encountering an issue where the time property is initially set to 0 instead of the value retrieved from local storage, and the timerId property is initially set to null instead of undefined. This is causing issues with the functionality of the component.

```
export const Header = () => {
    const {
        preferences: { time },
        time: { timer }
    } = useSelector((state: State) => state);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const [punctuation, setPunctuation] = useState(false);
    const [numbers, setNumbers] = useState(false);
    const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(2);
    const [option, setOption] = useLocalStorage("time", time || 60);

    const timeOptions = useMemo(() => [
        { id: 1, optionText: 15 },
        { id: 2, optionText: 30 },
        { id: 3, optionText: 60 },
        { id: 4, optionText: 120 },
    ], []);

    // initial setup of time property
    // get time from localStorage and set it to timer and time
    useEffect(() => {
        import(`../data/english.json`).then((words) =>
            dispatch(setWordList(words))
        );
        dispatch(timerSet(option));
        dispatch(setTime(option));
        setSelectedOption(timeOptions.find(opt => opt.optionText === option)?.id || 2);
    }, [dispatch, option, timeOptions]);

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(setTime(option));
        dispatch(timerSet(option));
        resetTest()
    }, [dispatch, option])

    return (
        <div className={styles.Container}>
            <div className={styles.NavBar} style={{ width: "44%" }}>
                <h1 className={styles.NavText} onClick={() => setPunctuation(!punctuation)} style={punctuation ? { color: 'var(--main-color)' } : { color: 'var(--sub-color)' }}>@punctuation</h1>
                <h1 className={styles.NavText} onClick={() => setNumbers(!numbers)} style={numbers ? { color: 'var(--main-color)' } : { color: 'var(--sub-color)' }}>#numbers</h1>
                <div className={styles.Divider}></div>
                <h1 className={styles.NavText} style={{ color: 'var(--main-color)' }}>time</h1>
                <div className={styles.Divider}></div>
                {timeOptions.map((option) => (
                    <NavOption
                        key={option.id}
                        optionText={option.optionText}
                        isSelected={option.id === selectedOption}
                        onClick={() => {
                            setSelectedOption(option.id);
                            setOption(option.optionText);
                        }}
                    />
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**resetTest()**

```
export const resetTest = () => {
    const wordElements = document.getElementsByClassName("word");
    if (wordElements.length > 0) {
        wordElements[0].scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "center" });
    }
    const { dispatch, getState } = store;
    const {
        time: { timerId },
        preferences: { time },
    } = getState();
    document
        .querySelectorAll(".wrong, .right")
        .forEach((el) => el.classList.remove("wrong", "right"));
    if (timerId) {
        clearInterval(timerId);
        dispatch(setTimerId(null));
    }
    import(`../data/english.json`).then((words) =>
        dispatch(setWordList(words.default))
    );
    dispatch(timerSet(time));
};
```

**Update**

Moving the retest() above the two dispatch actions
solved the problem but on page reload the option is initially 15 and then updates to the time retrieved from local storage

Comment: Do you realize that `dispatch(setTime(option))` and `dispatch(timerSet(option))` will run twice? This is because you have this function in both of the `useEffect` and `useEffect` will run once when the component is rendered. What does the `resetTest()` do at the second `useEffect`?

Comment: Yes, the resetTest clears another property called timerID and sets the time

Comment: @Ibrahim in the second useEffect when I moved resetTest to the top of the function, the timer works, why?

Comment: what is `resetTest`?